# I useing asp.netcore3.1 and I want read post request params from webservice but missing request params when using https?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, visual-studio, https

I create a filter to authentication http request like below:

```
    public class UseSSLAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage();
                msg.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                msg.ReasonPhrase = "SSL Needed!";
                actionContext.Response = msg;
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

and then use this filter for below action that call by webservice and read parameters from request. but when using https missing parameters but in http every parameter has value.

```
 [UseSSL]
       [RequireHttpsAttribute]
        public ActionResult SuccessPayment()
        {
            
            ViewBag.Bank = "ملت";
            string SaleReferenceId = "0";
            string ResCode ="0";
            string SaleOrderId = "0";
            string RefId = "0";
            var gg = "";
            if (Request.HasFormContentType == true)
            {
                if (Request.Form.ContainsKey("SaleReferenceId") == true)
                    SaleReferenceId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["SaleReferenceId"]) ? "0" : Request.Form["SaleReferenceId"].ToString();
                if (Request.Form.ContainsKey("ResCode") == true)
                    ResCode = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["ResCode"]) ? "0" : Request.Form["ResCode"].ToString();
                if (Request.Form.ContainsKey("SaleOrderId") == true)
                    SaleOrderId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["SaleOrderId"]) ? "0" : Request.Form["SaleOrderId"].ToString();
                if (Request.Form.ContainsKey("RefId") == true)
                    RefId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["RefId"]) ? "0" : Request.Form["RefId"].ToString();
                 gg = "oooooo";
            }
            var str=MellatReturn(SaleReferenceId, ResCode, SaleOrderId, RefId);
            ViewBag.temp = SaleReferenceId + "--" + ResCode + "--" + SaleOrderId + "--" + RefId+"--"+str+"--"+gg;
            return RedirectToAction("ShowMsg", "Home", new { msg = ViewBag.temp });
```

Prameters like 'RefId','SaleReferenceId','SaleOrderId','ResCode' after using HTTPS missing but when using HTTp all of them has value. where is my mistake?

Comment: HTTPS is using TLS.  SSL , TLS 1.0, and TLS1,1 are obsolete and will not work.  You must specify TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 may be using a new encryption mode and will not work with net core 3.1.   Net 4.7.2 or newer automatically using the operating system for TLS (not Net).  Then the operating system may need updates to work with TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  Also server has to be able to support TLS version and a certificate has to be common between client and server.  Lots of reasons to fail.

Comment: hi thanks for your aswer

Comment: but i update my asp.net framework to 5.0 but problem doesnt resolved

Comment: Still could be version of TLS being used is defaulting to obsolete version of TLS (not likely) or a missing certificate.